# How to access data from RestTemplate as List

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to access data from a spring boot service. The return type of the data is a `List`, but every time I access it, the list is empty.

This is my code:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("firstName", "test" );
params.put("lastName", "test1");
ResponseEntity<Person[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Person[].class, params);
```

In this case, `response.getBody()` is an empty `[]`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Person> searchUsers(
        @RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) String firstName,
        @RequestParam(value = "lastName", required = false) String lastName,
        @RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email {

    return personService.search(firstName, lastName, email, company);
}
```

I also tried with `String`, and `Person[]`, but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the REST API you're consuming isn't returning an empty array?

Comment: Yes. It is. The problem are the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GET
@Path("statement")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response statement(@QueryParam("from") String from, @QueryParam("to") String to) {
    DB idb = new DB();
    List<Transaction> transactions = idb.getTransactionsByDate(from, to);
    final GenericEntity<List<Transaction>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Transaction>>(transactions) {
    };
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(entity).build();
}
```